# Apply randomized CSS for each DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that every time the page loads, all my 'cards' are different colors. I have a 'randomizer' which randomizes the object, and then once that's run, I try to apply to my HTML elements. It doesn't seem to be working however and I'm having some trouble narrowing it down.

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    cardColors =  [{ top: '#68B78F', bottom: '#4CAF7C' }, 
                { top: '#9BC0CD', bottom: '#79B1C4' }, 
                { top: '#CDCA00', bottom: '#E7B700' },
                { top: '#C3322B', bottom: '#AF2B26' }];

    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      var color = cardColors.shuffle();
      console.log($(cards[0]));
      $(cards[i]).css('background-color', color[0].top);      
      $(cards[i]).css('background-color', color[0].bottom);  
    };
  });  

  Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var input = this;
    for (var i = input.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1)); 
      var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];    
      input[randomIndex] = input[i]; 
      input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return input;
  };
    </script>
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to display it through a Django template:

```
<div class="cards">
  {% for book in books %}
    {% for passage in highlighted %}
    <div class="card">
      <div></div>
      <p>{{book.title |safe }}</p>
      <p>{{book.author |safe }}</p>
      <p>{{passage |safe }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Aside from help, would also love to hear some refactoring suggestions!

Comment: So what actually happens when you try it?

Comment: Is this what you are getting http://jsfiddle.net/u309pgjm/

Comment: Refactor suggestion: Remove jQuery

Comment: Do you really need to shuffle the whole array each time through the loop just to select a random element from it?

Comment: @RonniSkansing Refactoring != Optimization

Comment: Personally I wouldn't extend the `array` prototype with new methods

Comment: Could you explain how it isn't working? @dev's fiddle seems to work, every time you load it you get different random colors for each card.

Comment: @A.Wolff I not pointing to optimization. I am pointing to *"reduced complexity to improve source code maintainability, and create a more expressive internal architecture or object model to improve extensibility."* -wikipedia. Which imo removing jQuery would do, no need for it in these cases for anything.

Comment: @RonniSkansing When it comes to readability/maintainability, i'd suggest (if already incuded) to use jQuery and its chainability concept, imho. OP is mixing both javascript and jQuery methods. He should use one or other but doesn't mix it like that, again imho

Comment: @A.Wolff +1 totally agree.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've recognized the fault lies in loading the js at the right time and not so much the source itself. @RonniSkansing I appreciate the suggestion, but as mentioned above, I use jQuery for readability and maintainability (less js written).

Comment: @SabbaPetri glad you worked it out. In your example it would be less code without jQuery.

Comment: @RonniSkansing If you have an alternate solution without jQuery and it's cleaner, I'd love to see it and learn from it!

Comment: @SabbaPetri `cards[i].style.backgroundColor = current_color.top;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I made small improvment for your code.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    cardColors =  [{ top: '#68B78F', bottom: '#4CAF7C' }, 
            { top: '#9BC0CD', bottom: '#79B1C4' }, 
            { top: '#CDCA00', bottom: '#E7B700' },
            { top: '#C3322B', bottom: '#AF2B26' }];

    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    var color = cardColors.shuffle();
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        current_color = color.pop();
        $(cards[i]).css('background-color', current_color.top);      
        $(cards[i]).css('background-color', current_color.bottom);  
    };
  });  

  Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var input = this;
    for (var i = input.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1)); 
      var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];    
      input[randomIndex] = input[i]; 
      input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return input;
  };
```

here is demonstration... http://jsfiddle.net/u309pgjm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go to more random approach which will display unique color each time untill each color gets displayed at least once.
My approach is based on storing the card colors which has not been displayed so far and selecting one out of them randomly. Thus it will not repeat a color untill each color used at least once. 
Below is the approach using localStorage:

```
var cardColors = [{id : 1,top : '#68B78F',bottom : '#4CAF7C'}];//id added to ease the comparison
var cardColor, usedCardColors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usedCardColors "));
if(usedCardColors === null) {
    usedCardColors = [];
}
var unUsedCardColors = difference(usedCardColors, cardColors, 'id');//id is the property to be compared
if(unUsedCardColors.length === 0) { //All cardColors  used at once
    //you may wish to restart all over by removing  localStorage usedCardColors
} else {
    cardColor = unUsedCardColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * unUsedCardColors.length)];
    localStorage.setItem("usedCardColors ", JSON.stringify(usedCardColors.push(cardColor)));
    applyColorToElements(cardColor); //loop to Elements to set color
}

function difference(a, b, pk) { //b -a //fn can be compacted by using array filter/map etc
    var c = [],found;
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        found = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if(a[j][pk] === b[i][pk]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            c.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```